# Testing a UITableView in a UIViewController programatically instantiated

Tags: swift, uitableview, xctest

I want to inject my data manager into my view controller and test it.

The ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var alert: AlertViewController?

    var coreDataManager: CoreDataManagerProtocol?

    init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManagerProtocol) {
        self.coreDataManager = coreDataManager
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.coreDataManager = CoreDataManager()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }

    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
        alert = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.alertStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.alerts.mainAlert) as? AlertViewController
        alert?.title = "Enter your task"
        alert?.presentToWindow()
        alert?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return coreDataManager?.getTasks().count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let data = coreDataManager?.getTasks()[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data?.value(forKey: Constants.entityNameAttribute) as? String
        return cell
    }
}
```

I want to test this through injecting at mock into the view controller:

```
class CoreDataManagerMock: CoreDataManagerProtocol {
    var storeCordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel!
    var store: NSPersistentStore!

    func getTasks() -> [NSManagedObject] {
        managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: nil)
        storeCordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

        do {
            store = try storeCordinator.addPersistentStore(
                ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // catch failure here
        }
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCordinator

        var localTasks = [NSManagedObject]()
        let entityOne = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: Constants.entityName, into: managedObjectContext)
        entityOne.setValue(false, forKey: Constants.entityCompletedattribute)
        entityOne.setValue("Enter your task", forKey: Constants.entityNameAttribute)
        localTasks.append(entityOne)
        return localTasks
    }

    func save(task: String) {
        //
    }

}
```

But I'm struggling to test this.

I can't request a cell as I'm not instantiating from the Storyboard (and I can't, since I need to inject the mock core manager.

In every test I try to run tableView resolves to nil

Here is my attempt, thinking I can test my cellForRowAt function directly:

```
    func testtv() {
        let CDM = CoreDataManagerMock()
        let viewController = ViewController(coreDataManager: CDM)

       viewController.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        viewController.tableView(UITableViewMock(), cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

        let actualCell = viewController.tableView?.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) )


        let test = viewController.tableView(UITableViewMock(), cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
        XCTAssertEqual(actualCell?.textLabel?.text, actualCell?.textLabel?.text)
    }
```

But as tableView is nil is nil so I can't register the cell. How can I test cellForRow(at: when I inject my dependency as above?

Comment: As a side note, unit tests for UI are often considered as bad. They are too complicated, you are generating too much code (which is often an exact duplicate of the implementation) and it's questionable whether the tests are actually useful. I would recommend to drop unit tests and go for full e2e tests, with no mocking. You will be able to test more use cases, with substantially less code.

Answer (score 0):

How I did testing with `UIStoryboard` instantiated `UIViewController`s was by doing this.

```
// STEP 1
// instantiate the storyboard
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SomeStoryboard", bundle: nil)

// STEP 2
// instantiate the UIViewController using the storyboard
let sampleViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleViewController") as! SampleViewController

// STEP 3
// set the properties you need to set 
sampleViewController.xxxxx = "foo"
sampleViewController.yyyyy = "bar"

// STEP 4
// call the view so the ui objects would be instantiated
// not doing this would cause a crash
// this also calls `viewDidLoad()`
_ = sampleViewController.view
```

So in your case since this is how the code would look like:

```
func testtv() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "INSERT STORYBOARD NAME HERE", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    viewController.coreDataManager = CoreDataManagerMock()
    _ = viewController.view

    // I'm not sure about the code below this comment
    // but the above code should work

    viewController.tableView(UITableViewMock(), cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

    let actualCell = viewController.tableView?.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) )

    let test = viewController.tableView(UITableViewMock(), cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
    XCTAssertEqual(actualCell?.textLabel?.text, actualCell?.textLabel?.text)
}
```

ViewController

Why this is, is because calling `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: _)` uses `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

You can remove this snippet below because you don't need it and it won't work since the `UIViewController` you're instantiating is from a storyboard.

```
init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManagerProtocol) {
    self.coreDataManager = coreDataManager
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

What you could do instead is create a static method to instantiate your `UIViewController` with the parameters you need. Example:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var someObject: SomeObject!

    static func instantiate(someObject: SomeObject) -> SomeViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SomeStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController")
        viewController.someObject = someObject
        return viewController
    }
}

// usage
let vc = SomeViewController.instantiate(someObject: SomeObject())
// or
let vc: SomeViewController = .instantiate(someObject: SomeObject())
```

Comment: This will work, and thank you, but directly injecting the dependencies like this does not seem a great solution (when writing tests how do you know the dependencies to be injected? What happens if you miss one?). There must be a better way, surely?

Comment: For my projects I either use the `Factory` pattern or for a much simpler solution just use a `static` method I to instantiate the storyboard `UIViewController`.

Comment: For storyboard-based view controllers, this is a good answer. If you want stronger dependency injection at the initializer level, you either need to move away from storyboards, or wait until you can use the new IBSegueAction that was just introduced at WWDC 2019.